# Python - Deep Copy without using copy module

Tags: python, python-3.x

Essentially, the problem was to create a function deepcopy(L) that will return a deep copy of a list L. However, we were told to not use the copy module or any function in it.

I'm a complete beginner in an intro class and am honestly struggling with this one. The only thing we were really told is that we should use recursion to solve the problem but after being stuck for so long I figured I'd ask for help.

Couldn't figure it out in class and didn't really get a clear answer and now the professor is moving on so ANY help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: We answer specific questions here. "ANY help would be greatly appreciated" isn't a question. You need to have a conversation with someone, and Stack Overflow isn't the place to do that.

Comment: If you want help with this you need to show us the code you've written so far and explain what it's doing wrong.

Comment: Sorry, this is the first time I've used the site. Truthfully, I don't even really know where to begin to make this work so I don't really have code written.

Comment: Do you have any experience writing recursive functions? Complete beginner aren't usually expected to write recursive code... This task isn't hard, but there are a few pitfalls. In particular, you need to be careful with strings.

Comment: Yeah, thats what everyone keeps telling me. The professor is purposely going much harder on us than you would expect in an intro class because he thinks this is the only way we'll learn anything. However it's like learning the spanish alphabet and then being told to go write an essay.

Comment: To answer you though, I do not have very much experience with writing recursive functions, especially in this context. I apologize for not submitting code in my question but like I said, I don't even really know where to begin and just want to figure this out.

Comment: basically show us your code, show us where it goes wrong, show us your input, show us your output, show us your expected output.... then ask us your question.

Comment: @EdwinvanMierlo Sorry, I don't really have code to post. I genuinely do not know how to do this, or how to even begin. It was brought up in class but I never figured it out and, as I said, the professor is now moving on and I just want to understand how this works. I can't stress enough that I am a beginner as well.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe, you are looking for something like this:

```
def mydeepcopy(L):
    if isinstance(L, list):
        ret = []
        for i in L:
            ret.append(mydeepcopy(i))
    elif isinstance(L, (int, float, type(None), str, bool)):
        ret = L
    else:
        raise ValueError("Unexpected type for mydeepcopy function")

    return ret

lst = [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9] ]
copy = mydeepcopy(lst)

print("Original Data: %s" % (lst))
print("Original IDs: %s = %s" % (id(lst),[ id(i) for i in lst ]))

print("Copied Data: %s" % (copy))
print("Copied IDs: %s = %s" % (id(copy),[ id(i) for i in copy ]))
```

Possible Output:

```
Original Data: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
Original IDs: 140637274065288 = [140637274064712, 140637274064776, 140637274065352]
Copied Data: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
Copied IDs: 140637274065480 = [140637274065416, 140637274065160, 140637274065096]
```

Answer (score 1):

Deepcopy can be done using this one line method,

```
def deep_copy(source_list):
    dest_list = source_list[:]
    return dest_list
```

It gives you the smaller function and reduce the processing time.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to pinpoint the fact that performing

```
dest_list = source_list[:]
```

does NOT create a **deepcopy**.

To prove this try performing the following operations:

```
>>> list1 = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
>>> list2 = list1[:]
>>> id(list1) == id(list2)
False
>>> id(list1[0]) == id(list2[0])
True
```

As the nested objects are just a copy of the reference, this operation classifies as **shallowcopy**

Answer (score 0):

It is a single line answer:

```
newList = [L[i] for i in range(len(L))]
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer above by Aaron is correct, except that each list in a list comprehension also needs to be a copy. So,

```
newList = [L[i].copy() for i in range(len(L))]
```