# Changing array variable changes another variable

Tags: python

In python, when I append to the "sim" variable the "history" variable changes.

```
history = [[[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]]]
sim = list(history[0])

sim[0].append(5)
```

Result: [[[1, 5], [2], [3], [4], [5]]]

How do I fix this? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the built-in `copy` module's [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html):

> Assignment statements in Python do not copy objects, they create
> bindings between a target and an object. For collections that are
> mutable or contain mutable items, a copy is sometimes needed so one
> can change one copy without changing the other. This module provides
> generic shallow and deep copy operations (explained below).

Your code, specifically the line `sim = list(history[0])` is making an assignment, not a copy of `history[0]`. It looks like you want a copy instead:

```
import copy

history = [[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]]]
sim = copy.deepcopy(history[0])

sim[0].append(5)

print(f"history:\t{history}")
print(f"sim:\t\t{sim}")

> history:  [[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]]]
> sim:      [[1, 5], [2], [3], [4], [5]]
```

Note: using `list()` to make a copy of a list creates a *shallow* copy, meaning only the top level of items is copied - the references to the *inner* lists still point to the same place. You can verify this by replacing the `copy.deepcopy()` with a `copy.copy()` - you'll get the same result as in the original post.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I added a note to address using how using `list()` to to copy lists only makes a shallow copy - which fails with the nested lists given in the original post.

Comment: Nice! Thank you. Would love to be able to do it without importing additional modules but oh well!

Comment: @prince888 while `copy` is a built-in module, you could implement your own recursive deepcopy function, eg.: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46873845/3434388